# VBScript WScript Db Connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, odbc

In my ASP code i have the following with no issues when running this as server side script with asp engine. However, when I run this same connection with VB Script in a VBS file, it never connects to the DB? I have windows 2008, and 2008 R2 MSSQL. Any ideas?

```
 establish connection 
function DatabaseConnection()

' establish connection if not connected already
if not IsObject(objGlobalConn) then
    if Len(Application("WebConnectionString")) = 0 then
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Application.Lock
        Application("WebConnectionString") = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\TB\ConnectionString3")
        Application.Unlock
    end if
    set objGlobalConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objGlobalConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
    objGlobalConn.CommandTimeOut = 0
    objGlobalConn.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
    objGlobalConn.Open Application("WebConnectionString")
end if

' return connection object
set DatabaseConnection = objGlobalConn

end function
```

My VBScript File:

```
' get the connection string
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sConnectionString  = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\TB\ConnectionString3")
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application object only exists when running VBScript under ASP.  If a .vbs file is run under the Windows Script Host (WSH) via WScript.exe or CScript.exe, the Application object is not available.  (I'm guessing there's an `On Error Resume Next` statement somewhere that's suppressing the error messages that WSH is raising.)

Two solutions come to mind, based on whether or not you really need to store the connection string in the Application object.  Assuming `Application("WebConnectionString")` isn't used outside of the `DatabaseConnection` function, the references to `Application` can be removed.  Then the function can run under both ASP and WSH:

```
function DatabaseConnection()
  Dim objGlobalConn, oShell, connectionString

  ' establish connection if not connected already
  if not IsObject(objGlobalConn) then
      Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      connectionString = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\TB\ConnectionString3")
      Set oShell = Nothing

      set objGlobalConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      objGlobalConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
      objGlobalConn.CommandTimeOut = 0
      objGlobalConn.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
      objGlobalConn.Open connectionString
  end if

  ' return connection object
  set DatabaseConnection = objGlobalConn

end function
```

However, if `Application("WebConnectionString")` is used outside of the `DatabaseConnection` function, a little more code is needed to get the function to work under both ASP and WSH.  Other parts of the code that reference the `Application` object, or any other ASP-related objects, will need to be similarly guarded with calls to `IsRunningUnderASP`:

```
function DatabaseConnection()
  Dim objGlobalConn, oShell, connectionString

  ' establish connection if not connected already
  if not IsObject(objGlobalConn) then
      Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      connectionString = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\TB\ConnectionString3")
      Set oShell = Nothing

      If IsRunningUnderASP() And (Len(Application("WebConnectionString")) = 0) then
          Application.Lock
          Application("WebConnectionString") = connectionString
          Application.Unlock
      End If

      set objGlobalConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      objGlobalConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
      objGlobalConn.CommandTimeOut = 0
      objGlobalConn.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient
      objGlobalConn.Open connectionString
  end if

  ' return connection object
  set DatabaseConnection = objGlobalConn

end function

Function IsRunningUnderASP
  IsRunningUnderASP = _
    IsObject(Application) And _
    IsObject(Request) And _
    IsObject(Response)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure why this worked well on 2003 and not 2008? Windows obviously changed their settings for these types of connections.

Comment: Just fyi, your script is not working either in VBS, which is where I needed it. Im guessing there is more to this than simple changes to code.

Comment: The connection inside a VBs File. I already have it working in asp and through the scripts via IIS. VBS files run from command are not connecting. They don't error, but they just timeout.

Comment: Is there an `On Error Resume Next` statement in your code?  If so, remove it.  It's possible an error is occurring, but that statement is suppressing the error message.

Comment: The issue was that the default scripting host was wscript rather than cscript. Changing that, allowed the scripts to work by default for all directories.